# ebay api finding items SortOrderType = EndTimeSoonest

Tags: javascript, ebay-api

I would retrieve some listings with ebay and order it with:

```
    •   EndTimeSoonest
(in) Sorts items by end time, with items ending soonest listed first.
```

So I have set this url:

```
 var url ="http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
            url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
            url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
            url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=xxxxxx";
            url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-"+loc;
            url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
            url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
            url +="callback=e";
            url += "&keywords="+mystring;
            url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=50";
                url += "&SortOrderType=EndTimeSoonest";         
            url += urlfilter;
```

The problem is that results are not ordered by ending time of auctions.
What I am doing wrong?
Here there is the SortOrder guide: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/findItemsAdvanced.html#Request.sortOrder

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input is 'sortOrder=EndTimeSoonest' not SortOrderType!
You could also do with '&paginationInput.pageNumber=NUMBER' to fullfill the pagination contract.